# How to utilize IPMI on Windows?

Tags: remote, electrical-power, ipmi, drac

My organization is primarily a Dell shop running Windows.  Most are recent models that support [IPMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface) 2.0. (Dell 1950, for example).

At a minimum I'd like to use IPMI to perform remote chassis power on/off, such as when a server is hung and no one is available at the NOC to hard boot it.  Then, I'd like to see what else it can do.

Configuring it is not easy.  I've tried the [ipmiutil](http://ipmiutil.sourceforge.net/) tool.  I was able to view [BMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseboard_Management_Controller) configuration and configure it to some degree.  I don't think I understand the configuration requirements well enough to know how to enable it.  I'm also aware of an [ipmitool](http://ipmitool.sourceforge.net/) tool, but it only runs on Unix/Linux.

What I'd like to do is share the same ethernet port for server OS and BMC, since it's an option, giving the BMC its own IP.

You may be thinking: "Doesn't Dell have a [DRAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_DRAC) card that does IPMI and more?"  Yes, and we have the DRAC 5 cards in all of these.  Configuring that for remote power management has been just as much of a mystery.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

SuperMicro has a [Java-based IPMIView tool that you might find useful](http://www.servethehome.com/download-supermicro-ipmiview-latest-version/).

In my experience, DRACs are easiest to manage via their telnet or ssh interface - the other tools tend to be a bit flaky.

[This page](http://wiki.adamsweet.org/doku.php?id=ipmi_on_linux) is linux-oriented but provides a decent overview of IPMI tools.

Comment: Isn t the java based tool view only?

Answer (score 3):

Dell has BMC Utility package that install the tools in windows, http://dell.to/L13j0x, and allows you start/stop, read the BMC logs, etc...

Comment: This is the correct answer - the question is Windows specific and this tool does the job (even using Windows 10 as a client and connecting to old BMC 1.4.0 PowerEdge 1425SC)

Comment: @Coré link is no longer valid.

Comment: Hi, I imagine it is already late but if you want to find the bmc utility, just look for "dell bmc utility" in your favorite search engine, here you have the search in Google. https://www.google.com/search?q=dell+bmc+utility&oq=Dell+bmc+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j0i22i30l3.6423j0j7&client=ms-android-samsung-gs-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8