# Limiting in-band OS access to Supermicro BMC (AST2500) possible?

Tags: security, ipmi, supermicro, bmc

TL;DR: Is there any option to disable OS (in-band) access to Aspeed AST 2500 BMC on a SuperMicro board or at least limit it somehow (e.g. via specific password or via setting the permission level to read-only access)?

Long version:

Last year we bought a few SuperMicro servers containing an Aspeed AST2500 BMC. Up to now we were not using the BMCs but now are in the process of setting them up, reachable via a separate out-of-band management network. While researching options to reset BMC passwords I found multiple posts (e.g. [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/85042/is-it-possible-to-reset-the-password-on-a-supermicro-ipmi-interface)) which indicate as soon as I've got root privileges on the host I can also access the BMC and change the admin password without any additional security measures.

I really don't like the idea of being able to change BMC parameters from within the host OS, especially because BMCs are often badly patched and are a very interesting target for rootkits (by the way, exactly such [a rootkit was discovered the other day](https://threats.amnpardaz.com/en/2021/12/28/implant-arm-ilobleed-a); at least, as far as I know, it could not get onto the BMC via in-band interface)

Is there any option to limit host-to-BMC communication?

EDIT: The server board used in our servers is "ASRock ROMED8-2T".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** I am not aware of a BMC setting telling it "disable all in-band access", but I really doubt it exists *or it can be useful at all*

**Long answer:** While your question is interesting, please note that if someone gained root privileges your server is *irrecoverably compromised*, so you can not trust it anymore. After all, root is able to not only reset the BMC password, but to also reflash it, rewrite the mainboard BIOS/UEFI and updating the firmware of other add-on cards (ie: RAID controllers).

All of that can be accomplished by standard low-level interfaces (I2C, DMI, IPMI, etc.) which the linux kernel natively supports. Removing the corresponding modules/code will not work, as a bad actor having root privileges can install and reboot a patched kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - of course you are absolutely right about a server being "irrecoverably compromised" if an attacker gained root access. In fact, I asked about ways to limit communication because I want to prevent an attacker from gaining access to the management network via the BMC. But apparently there is no such option...